# Help!!!! Homepage is broke. Styles are all messed up but only on the homepage

Tags: magento2.3, home-page, merge-css

I need help. Our site Front end home page is broke. I have `rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*.` Then I ran magento Commands.

```
1- set maintenance mode
php bin/magento maintenance:enable

2- Upload module or use composer to install module using cli

3- Enable module
php bin/magento module:enable MyCompany_MyModule

4- upgrade database
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

5-compile your code
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

6-static content deploy 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

7-reindex (optional)
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

8-clear cache
php bin/magento cache:flush

9-Disable maintenance mode
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set it to production mode that sometimes solves problems like you are having:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

then it generated all static content that is needed.

Comment: This is our Live store. Its always in Production. Can I switch to developer mode then back to Production mode? Or is that bad to switch Production mode back to Developer Mode?

Comment: Yes, try that, should be no problems

Comment: Awesome, ok I got scared to turn it in developer mode. But another developer on my team helped me.  I cleared pub/_cache file. Then I turned off merging CSS/JS. 
`bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0
bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0`.
Then ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US` then I cleaned cache and it fixed everything.

Comment: Its always scary when using the cli on live site and jumping between different modes and running commands. There are so many dependencies that need to work and it feels a bit random systems, especially if one works with bloated themes. Good that it worked, have a nice day!

Comment: Ok. So its actually better to turn back in to developer Mode and then back to Production Mode? I will do that in the future honestly. I feel that would be better as well and easy to debug.

Comment: My personal experience is that the command deploy:mode:set production tend to solve problems with broken themes like you had, it takes longer time but it makes it more automatic and generates all the static content for sure. In your situation it would probably have been possible to run setup:static-content:deploy with the correct flag to get the same result. It should be safe to do as you write and turn it between production and developer mode.